# MySQL advanced calculation based on two columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to figure out if I can use MySQL workbench to give me some advanced calculations based on **id, statement_one and latest_statement.** My base table looks like this:

[image]

Basically I would like the **test column** to shown as below:

- for id=1, the test column show "1" from 2019Q3 to 2021Q2 and everything else shows "0".
- for id=22, the test column show "1" from 2019Q2 to 2021Q3 and everything else shows "0".

[image]

Anyone knows which function I can use to create a calculation **based on the statement_one and last_statement range for each id?** Thank you in advance for your help here!

Comment: Next time try to write text using a markdown table (not to paste images) when possible. You can try this [web](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a query like this:

First I get first_statement (`MIN`) and last_statement (`MAX`) for each `id`, then I `JOIN` `cte` subquery with the original table and use `CASE` statement to calculate `test` column.

**MySql >= 8.0**

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT id,  MIN(statement_one) AS fs, MAX(latest_statement) AS ls
             FROM t
             GROUP BY id)
             
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN quarter >= cte.fs AND quarter <= cte.ls THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS test
FROM t
INNER JOIN cte ON t.id = cte.id;
```

**MySql < 8.0**

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN quarter >= sq.fs AND quarter <= sq.ls THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS test
FROM t
INNER JOIN (SELECT id,  MIN(statement_one) AS fs, MAX(latest_statement) AS ls
             FROM t
             GROUP BY id) AS sq ON t.id = sq.id;
```

| id | quarter | statement_one | latest_statement | id | fs | ls | test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019Q1 |  |  | 1 | 2019Q3 | 2021Q2 | 0 |
| 1 | 2019Q2 |  |  | 1 | 2019Q3 | 2021Q2 | 0 |
| 1 | 2019Q3 | 2019Q3 |  | 1 | 2019Q3 | 2021Q2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2019Q4 |  |  | 1 | 2019Q3 | 2021Q2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020Q1 |  |  | 1 | 2019Q3 | 2021Q2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020Q2 |  |  | 1 | 2019Q3 | 2021Q2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020Q3 |  |  | 1 | 2019Q3 | 2021Q2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020Q4 |  |  | 1 | 2019Q3 | 2021Q2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021Q1 |  |  | 1 | 2019Q3 | 2021Q2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021Q2 |  | 2021Q2 | 1 | 2019Q3 | 2021Q2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021Q3 |  |  | 1 | 2019Q3 | 2021Q2 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021Q4 |  |  | 1 | 2019Q3 | 2021Q2 | 0 |
| 22 | 2019Q1 |  |  | 22 | 2019Q2 | 2021Q3 | 0 |
| 22 | 2019Q2 | 2019Q2 |  | 22 | 2019Q2 | 2021Q3 | 1 |
| 22 | 2019Q3 |  |  | 22 | 2019Q2 | 2021Q3 | 1 |
| 22 | 2019Q4 |  |  | 22 | 2019Q2 | 2021Q3 | 1 |
| 22 | 2020Q1 |  |  | 22 | 2019Q2 | 2021Q3 | 1 |
| 22 | 2020Q2 |  |  | 22 | 2019Q2 | 2021Q3 | 1 |
| 22 | 2020Q3 |  |  | 22 | 2019Q2 | 2021Q3 | 1 |
| 22 | 2020Q4 |  |  | 22 | 2019Q2 | 2021Q3 | 1 |
| 22 | 2021Q1 |  |  | 22 | 2019Q2 | 2021Q3 | 1 |
| 22 | 2021Q2 |  |  | 22 | 2019Q2 | 2021Q3 | 1 |
| 22 | 2021Q3 |  | 2021Q3 | 22 | 2019Q2 | 2021Q3 | 1 |
| 22 | 2021Q4 |  |  | 22 | 2019Q2 | 2021Q3 | 0 |